# Simplify $\frac{1}{\ln2}[\ln N! - \ln N_1! - \ln N_0!]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, information-theory, entropy, biology

We are asked to simply
$$ H= \displaystyle \frac{1}{\ln 2}[\ln N! - \ln N_1! - \ln N_0!] $$ to $$rT\log_2\left(\frac{e}{r\Delta \tau }\right)$$ where $N_0 = (1-p)N,\, N_1 = pN, N = \displaystyle \frac{T}{\Delta\tau}, \, p = r\Delta\tau $, using Stirling's approximation $\ln x! \approx x(\ln x - 1)$.

So far I have, 
\begin{align} 
H &= \frac{1}{\ln 2}[N(\ln N - 1) - N_1(\ln N_1 - 1) - N_0(\ln N_0 - 1)]\\
&= \frac{1}{\ln 2}[N\ln N - N_1\ln N_1- N_0\ln N_0]\\
&= \frac{1}{\ln 2}[N\ln N - pN\ln pN- (1-p)N\ln (1-p)N]\\
&= \frac{1}{\ln 2}[N\ln N - pN\ln p- pN\ln N- (1-p)N\ln (1-p) - (1-p)N\ln N]\\
&= \frac{1}{\ln 2}[-pN\ln p- (1-p)N\ln (1-p)]
\end{align}
and that's where I'm stuck

Comment: I think that you need to know that $p \ll 1$. If so, you can argue that $-(1-p) \ln(1-p) = p + O(p^2),$ and you're left with the main term $Np/\ln(2) ( 1 + \ln(1/p) )$ which simplifies to the given expression.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that $p = r\Delta \tau$ is so small that we can approximate $\ln(1-p)$ by $\ln(1) = 0$, from that assumption it should be fairly straightforward.